# Is it possible to implement both Spring OAuth2.0 and basic authentication when application running on localhost?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, oauth-2.0

My question is upper) I'm building Client-Server app on java and want to try implement OAuth2.0 authentication. Yet there is a problem - I haven't static IP address. Could I implement it whith such services like Google or Facebook when my app is on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, some of the OAuth providers won't even accept IP addresses, so even if you have a static IP it won't work.
You can try to use localhost, but that is not always possible or desirable, for instance when you want to test over a local network.

There is another way to get around this. What you can do is:

- Pick a domain name which will never exist. For example: `random.rubbish`
- Setup your OAuth apps with this domain name, i.e. register with Facebook and Google using `http://random.rubbish/` as your domain and you can add a path if you want. This is only an example, you can change http and random.rubbish to whatever you need.
- Now on your local system, you can edit the [HOSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file and put an entry for random.rubbish as follows: `random.rubbish 127.0.0.1`
- Now in your browser when you go to `http://random.rubbish`, it will take you to localhost (port 80 because of http). This is because the first check the system performs to resolve a domain name is the HOSTS file.

If you want to test over a local network, you can add this entry to your DHCP server, or you can edit the HOSTS file on every machine where you will be accessing the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one more question. If basic home address of my app is `localhost:8081/FoodService` what should I do with custom port(non 8080) in my HOSTS file?

Comment: Hosts file will not accept port, but you can still use random.rubbish:8081/FoodService for your OAuth requests, from what I know the providers shouldn't reject your request based on port number, they only care about the domain

Comment: Clear. And also how to implement two ways of authentication basic and oAuth2 in Spring. Actually I want to have on my login page button SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK and basic form with login and pass. Is it possible in Spring Security? If yes, how do I should save my users data in the database?

Comment: This is a new question, you should ask it in a new post, but this has been answered several times so you should search on SO and the internet first before you ask the question.